# How to maintain a gnome-extension collaboratively?

Tags: authorization, gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

The [gnome-shell-extensions site](https://extensions.gnome.org/upload/) supports only personal accounts for uploading.  How can i do collaborative development with multiple maintainers for an extension, without sharing account credentials?

For instance:

- GitHub does that with "collaborators" or "organizations".
- PyPi supports [x2 collaborator roles](https://pypi.org/help/#collaborator-roles): owner & maintainer

Answer (score 1):

At this time, there is no support for organization accounts on extensions.gnome.org. This is planned as part of the long running [Rethinking extensions.gnome.org](https://gitlab.gnome.org/Infrastructure/extensions-web/-/issues/116) (see [#43](https://gitlab.gnome.org/Infrastructure/extensions-web/-/issues/43)).

For now, the best suggestion is to just delegate release duties to one member. Other than that, shared credentials are unfortunately necessary for now.